Are there any direct ferries between South Korea and Taiwan?
My plan is to travel between South Korea to Taiwan or the Philippines by sea. I'm looking for a ferry without having to change in China or Japan.

It's ~1300km from Busan to Taipei and ~2400km from Busan to Manila.  That's not a typical ferry trip IMO
